# Adding Buttons to a message in Telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-group

See the following screenshot:

[image]

How did he add those buttons?
I know it can be done via the BOT API but this is not a bot...

Comment: did you get this message in a group?

Answer (score 3):

There are bots that will help you compose messages, perhaps that is what you are seeing?

As an example, see https://t.me/ControllerBot.